# How to avoid Kessler syndrome with human made satellites?

Tags: momentum, orbital-motion, laser, space, satellites

It has been a year that I am dreaming to find a way to destroy a satellite **in a clean way** (push out of orbit or reentrance).

I first tought to use the momentum of laser to push a satellite out of orbit but apparently it takes to much energy and this kind of laser is impossible for the actual technology of our century.

The Russian have demonstrated how they would detroy a satellite, but it seems problematic since it encourages the Kessler syndrome.

How would you detroy a satellite for cheap without causing space junk?

Does all satellite have a way to communicate with earth ? Could we tell them to reenter the atmosphere so they get destroyed? If so, what kind of communication protocol do they use ?

Don't take me wrong, I am just curious about the research done by the others about this subject. The main goal of this question is to understand and find ways to avoid space junk. It's not about "destroying" satellites for fun.

Comment: Note this stuff would be illegal in so many ways and even planning it could be illegal.  Just the part about interfering with communications of any kind is illegal almost everywhere without explicit government permission.

Comment: I updated my question. Don't take me wrong. I want to know what are the actual solutions in place to avoid space junk with the satellites. I want to know what are we actually doing to avoid the Kessler effect.

Comment: Many of users in this site are Russians (a rather common thing in science), so better avoid referring to what they do as "barbarian" ;)

Comment: @RogerVadim I've met quite a few russians, and let me reassure you that their skin is not as thin as the one from present americans or western europeans :-) they would probably be entertained by the comment

Comment: @lurscher I *am* entertained :)

Comment: If you want to know how space junk is being dealt with and plans for it the correct forum is [space.se].  Note the authorities do monitor websites (and they'd be negligent if they didn't).  And if you want to know what happens when you go too far down the road of being "interested" into the land of "obsessed", look up [Gerald Bull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerald_Bull) - yes, that kind of thing does happen in the real world.

Comment: @StephenG Thanks! I learned a lot with your reference of Gerald Bull. I didn't know about space gun before. But missile and projectile doesn't seems to be the cleanest way to end life of a satellite. I'm gonna do some reading on "Space exploration" as you suggest. I hope there is some guideline to force satellite manufacturer to force a reentrance or something like that at the end of the satellite life.  Still, it won't resolve the problem for the old unused satellites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal case for obvious reasons is when you can incorporate self-destruction into the satellite design. Even without fuel a system could be designed to incorporate a realignable solar sail designed to slowly decrement periapsis so that atmospheric drag would accelerate the process of atmospheric re-entry. It wouldn't be a bad idea that all satellites are designed with some sort of regulatory mechanism toward this. Why this hasn't happened so far is a political subject, so I won't touch it here

In the case of military takedown, I think keeping it cheap and keeping it clean are two inherently conflicting design goals. Cheapest is obviously aiming a laser and frying the equipment on-board. But this will definitely not be the cleanest, as the satellite would remain as orbital detritus essentially forever, or until hitting something else. In both cases, accelerating [Kessler syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kessler_syndrome)

The cleanest would be seizing it physically, or perhaps hacking its navigation controls to induce self-destruction